# Is reinterpret_cast any slower than a static_cast?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I'm comparing two pointers of class typedef `value_type` which are each of type `T*` or `char16_t`.

The compiler complains that I can't compare the two because they are distinct types:

```
'some_type1<char16_t>::value_type*' and 'some_type2<char16_t>::value_type*' lacks a cast
```

Strangely, I can't `static_cast<>` between the two:

```
invalid static_cast from type 'some_type1<char16_t>::value_type*' to type 'char16_t*'
```

Does it make a difference whether I use `reinterpret_cast<>` to compare or just `static_cast<>` both sides to `void*`?

I read somewhere that `reinterpret_cast<>` is done at runtime but I'm not sure.

**UPDATE**

I was under the false impression that `reinterpret_cast<>` was done at runtime. With further discussion I now understand that it is purely a compile-time construct.

Curiously though, it's also been demonstrated that `static_cast<>` *can* have runtime costs where a particular object is cast into another by matching against a constructor.

For exmaple, you can cast a primitive `int` to a vector with `static_cast<>`. It would seem that this is true for all cases where `static_cast<T>(e)` would be valid.

Comment: Slower? It's all done during compilation, do you really care how long it takes for the compiler to do the job?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and clarify the problem. For example, the following conflicts with itself; `char16_t` cannot be equivalent to a pointer type: _which are each of type `T*` or `char16_t`_

Comment: If you are ever not sure you should check the [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).  Yes there may be errors with it(i have seen 2 in the years I have used it) but it is a good place to start if you do not remember how something works.

Comment: When you refer to a pointer of the `char16_t`, do you mean `char16_t*`? The former is an integer type, not a pointer.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The two pointers are completely unrelated, so what does casting one to another and than comparing gives you?

Comment: I was trying to silence the compiler error.

Comment: @Zhro, not a valid goal by any means. You need to re-adjust your attitude towards compiler errors and warnings - they are your best friends. Trully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<>` is purely a compile-time cast. You're just reinterpreting what the underlying type is, completely sidestepping the type system. There is no possible runtime aspect.

`static_cast<>` *can* have a runtime cost, depending on what it is you're `static_cast`-ing. If you're casting a `void*`, or through an non-polymorphic object hierarchy, there will be no runtime cost. If you're casting through a polymorphic object hierarchy, there will be offset changes due the vtable which have to happen at runtime.

And if you're casting outside of a hierarchy, then you have to actually create a new object. Whether that looks like calling a conversion function:

```
struct A {
    operator B() { /* something */ }
};

A a;
static_cast<B>(a);
```

Or a converting constructor:

```
static_cast<std::vector<int>>(4);
```

that `static_cast<>` creates a whole new object - so definitely some code will need to be run to do this!

Comment: I didn't know you could `static_cast<>` primitive types to objects. Is it just looking at each constructor for a compatible type?

Comment: @Zhro `static_cast<T>(e)` is valid iff `T t(e)` is valid.

Comment: Nice. Does the last statement also apply when casting a floating point instance to a fixed point instance or vice-versa?

Comment: @barakmanos You mean like `static_cast<int>(2.0)`? Yeah, that has to do *something*

Comment: Well, I was actually thinking of the old C-style cast. I've always wondered how it was possible to perform that cast without actually changing the "bit-contents" of the operand during runtime.

Comment: @barakmanos C-style cast tries to do lots of different casts. If you did `(int)2.0` that would end up doing a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

Even when no custom type conversion logic is involved, `static_cast` might have a (unnoticeable) run-time performance. This is due to the fact that in case of multiple inheritance, `static_cast` needs to adjust offsets to bases, and this would require run-time arithmetics. While the effect is trully miniscule, it is there. It is clear from the following code sample:

```
struct Mother {
  virtual ~Mother(); 
  virtual void mother();
};

struct Father { 
  virtual ~Father();
  virtual void father();
};

struct Offspring: Mother, Father {
  void mother();
  void father();
};

void foo(Offspring* offspring) {
  Mother* mother = offspring;
  mother->mother();
}
```

The ASM code for function `foo()` has following piece of line:

```
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
```

That is the base offset. If you remove the cast, you will see this line disappearing.

On the other hand, `reinterpret_cast` is trully compile-time only cast and has no effect whatsoever during program run.

Answer (score 2):

> I read somewhere that `reinterpret_cast` is done at runtime but I'm not sure.

No, that's wrong (from what ever source you've got that).

`reinterpret_cast<>` and `static_cast<>` are both resolved at compile time (as you see from the compiler error).

`static_cast<>` is slightly slower than `reinterpret_cast<>` because some calculations for the offsets against the base class needs to be inserted in the emitted code.

May be you were confusing that with `dynamic_cast<>` which is indeed done at runtime, and performing a bit slower than a `reinterpret_cast<>` or `static_cast<>`.

Comment: This answers the question by invalidating the premise. I don't know where I read this but I couldn't find a source confirming whether it was runtime or compile-time. It may have been a false assumption against `static_cast` being compile-time.

Comment: Your last statement pretty much contradicts the rest of your answer IMO. How can you compare the speed of two elements which are running in two different scopes?

Comment: @barakmanos Doesn't dynamic cast have to be slower since it is done at run time.  Any cast done at compile time cost 0 at run time.

Comment: Makes sense. Whether the premise was invalid or not, I wasn't able to find an answer by searching. This question is still useful for anyone else who might be confused on the subject. I think downvoting it is a bit harsh.

Comment: @barakmanos How's that contradictorily? `dynamic_cast` is done at runtime and emits more code that will perform slower.

Comment: You do answer question literally, but I doubt it actually does any service to OP :)

Comment: @NathanOliver: The speed of compilation-time casts during runtime is zero **by definition** (and as pretty rightfully noted by the author). I just think that the comparison is pointless to begin with.

Comment: You can't say that `static_cast` has no effect during runtime. It does.

Comment: static_cast is **not** a compile-time only cast.

Comment: @SergeyA: As Zhro, I also don't understand this statement (except, perhaps, when casting from floating point types to fixed point types).

Comment: @barakmanos, the statment *have any impact on performance at runtime* is plain wrong.

Comment: @SergeyA: Please explain by an example of a compilation-time cast which yields an additional code.

Comment: @SergeyA: Right...  I would really love to see that the generated assembly of your example actually contains an additional piece of code (not being sarcastic of course, just a little doubtful). I believe that `static_cast` should generate a compilation error if the cast requires such thing as offset adjustment (thus justifying its "static-ness").

Comment: @barakmanos `struct A { operator B() { /* do lots of stuff here */; } }; A a; static_cast<B>(a);` would do stuff.

Comment: @Barry Overloading option of the cast operator is a pretty good point.